# How to embed a live and editable data table within a PowerBI report for forecasting

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am looking for a solution within PowerBI. There is a a [Visual Planning demo available from Power On](https://poweronbi.com/powerbi-visual-planning-demo/). This is what I am looking to achieve, but I want to create it myself so we can adopt it within our business for quarterly forecasting. I don't want to pay for a product developed by others.

There has to be a technique I am missing here somewhere that allows a LIVE data table to be edited within a report. I see they use a Save button, so this must be refreshing the data back to a spreadsheet or SharePoint list somewhere. Is it simply a SharePoint list displayed within the report, edited within the report and then 'saved' back to the list as a refresh?

Any assistance or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You're asking how to reverse engineer the custom visual they've developed?

Comment: Effectively yes. The video linked above shows how the visualisations change as the forecast is amended within the table. This would show our managers the effect the changes they are making to their forecast is having in a simple to understand manner.

Clearly Power On have developed a method of delivering this fully within PowerBI and I want to know how they did it.